# how to retrieve all venues using four square api

Tags: api, list, foursquare

I understand that we can search for the venues using a search term and ll. I want to be able to cache all the venues. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to retrieve all of foursquare's venues -- they're only available via search API endpoints. Results that are retrieved via these endpoints may be cached for up to 30 days.